# MissingReferenceException: The variable menuComponents of MenuHierarchyOrder doesn't exist anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a script to make the menus in my game to be properly activated according to my liking.

I have this script:

```
public class MenuHierarchyOrder : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<MenuHierarchyIndex> menuComponents;

    public void SetDefaultMenuOrder() {
        if (menuComponents != null)
        {            
            foreach (MenuHierarchyIndex item in menuComponents)
            {
                if (!item.gameObject.activeSelf) item.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                
                if (item.TryGetComponent<MenuHierarchyOrder>(out var subMenu))
                {
                    subMenu.SetDefaultMenuOrder();
                }
    
                if (item.GetMenuIndex() != 0)
                {
                    item.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("menuComponents is null. Make sure it's properly initialized.", gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And `SetDefaultMenuOrder()` is called in here first:

```
public class LoadManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<MenuHierarchyOrder> menuHierarchyOrders;

    private void Start() {
        LoadMenus();
    }

    private void LoadMenus() {
        foreach (var menu in menuHierarchyOrders)
        {
            if (!menu.gameObject.activeSelf) menu.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            menu.SetDefaultMenuOrder();
            menu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I only get the error whenever `SetDefaultMenuOrder()` is called a second time inside it's own function when checking if the `items` in `menuComponents` also have the `MenuHierarchyOrder` script.

It's bugging me because if I try to check if `item == null` it says it's null. But right after that if I try to get the item with `Debug.Log(item)` it gets the variable... Same if I just search right of `List<MenuHierarchyIndex> menuComponents`

It even might be a small thing but I just can't get my hands around it...

The ERROR:

> "MissingReferenceException: The variable menuComponents of
> MenuHierarchyOrder doesn't exist anymore. You probably need to
> reassign the menuComponents variable of the 'MenuHierarchyOrder'
> script in the inspector."

It's supposed to make the panels be active or inactive properly when you start the game even if I left them all wrong on the editor.

Comment: you need to debug it tbh you shouldnt need to set the order more than once..

Comment: I debugged it... The weird part is when I get the error, if I check to see if the variable is null it isn't... But gives the error that the variable is missing...

Comment: it suggests when the code started it was a different version of itself..

Comment: yeah it was but the object where the script was was still active. And the variables were populated in the inspector as well...